# Simplifying Nested Mapply Statements

Tags: r

I am trying to replace multiple individual mapply statements with a single, condensed set of code. I finally got it to work with 3 nested mapply statements, but that seems a bit convoluted of an approach. I am new to R from other languages, so looking for some help to think in the R mentality. If the 3 statements is the best approach, I can live with it but looking for input. If you have a better way to structure subsetted outputs like this, I am all ears.

```
payments <- data.frame(
  Amount = sample(5:15,100,replace=TRUE),
  Tip.Amount = round(runif(100,0,2),2),
  "A" = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),100,replace=TRUE),
  "B" = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),100,replace=TRUE),
  "C" = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),100,replace=TRUE),
  "D" = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),100,replace=TRUE),
  "E" = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),100,replace=TRUE),
  "F" = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),100,replace=TRUE),
  Date = sample(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2016-01-31"),by="day"),100,replace=TRUE)
)
employees <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
dots <- lapply(c(employees,"Date"),as.symbol)

payments.by_date_employee <- payments %>%
  filter(!is.na(Date),!is.na(Amount)) %>%
  group_by_(.dots=dots) %>%
  summarise(Payment.Count=n(), Amount=sum(Amount),
            Tip.Count=sum(Tip.Amount>=0.01,na.rm=TRUE), Tip.Amount=sum(Tip.Amount,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Date)

#long/manual way--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
t <- list()
t[["payments"]][["amount"]] <- mapply(function(name) list({
  t.test(subset(payments,payments[[name]]==TRUE)$Amount,
         subset(payments,payments[[name]]==FALSE)$Amount)$p.value
}),
employees)

t[["payments"]][["count"]] <- mapply(function(name) list({
  t.test(subset(payments.by_date_employee,payments.by_date_employee[[name]]==TRUE)$Amount,
         subset(payments.by_date_employee,payments.by_date_employee[[name]]==FALSE)$Amount)$p.value
}),
employees)

t[["tips"]][["amount"]] <- mapply(function(name) list({
  t.test(subset(payments,payments[[name]]==TRUE)$Tip.Amount,
         subset(payments,payments[[name]]==FALSE)$Tip.Amount)$p.value
}),
employees)

t[["tips"]][["count"]] <- mapply(function(name) list({
  t.test(subset(payments.by_date_employee,payments.by_date_employee[[name]]==TRUE)$Tip.Amount,
         subset(payments.by_date_employee,payments.by_date_employee[[name]]==FALSE)$Tip.Amount)$p.value
}),
employees)
#long/manual way--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#attempt at single mapply statement ------------------------------------------------------------
y <- mapply(function(name,type,variable,df,nm) list({
  t.test(subset(eval(df),eval(df)[[name]]==TRUE)[[nm]],
         subset(eval(df),eval(df)[[name]]==FALSE)[[nm]])$p.value}),
  employees,
  c("payments","payments","tips","tips"),
  c("amount","count"),
  c(quote(payments),quote(payments),quote(payments.by_date_employee),quote(payments.by_date_employee)),
  c("Amount","Amount","Tip.Amount","Tip.Amount"),
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE
)
#attempt at single mapply statement ------------------------------------------------------------

#works but seems convoluted --------------------------------------------------------------------
z <- mapply(function(type) list({
  mapply(function(variable,df,nm) list({
    t[[type]][[variable]] <-mapply(function(name) list({
      t.test(subset(eval(df),eval(df)[[name]]==TRUE)[[nm]],
             subset(eval(df),eval(df)[[name]]==FALSE)[[nm]])$p.value}),
      employees)
  }),
  c("amount","count"),
  c(quote(payments),quote(payments),quote(payments.by_date_employee),quote(payments.by_date_employee)),
  c("Amount","Amount","Tip.Amount","Tip.Amount"),
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE
  )
}),
c("payments","tips")
)
#works but seems convoluted --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that breaks the problem into a few steps.  First, write a function that takes the name of a dataframe, a variable name, and an employee code, and returns the desired value:

```
ttest <- function(data, varname, employee) {
  d <- get(data)
  do.call(t.test, setNames(split(d[[varname]], d[[employee]]), c("x", "y")))$p.value
}
```

Now, use `mapply` to apply the function over vectors of dataframe names, variable names, and employee codes:

```
out <- mapply(ttest, 
  rep(c("payments", "payments.by_date_employee"), each = length(employees)), 
  c(rep(c("Amount", "Tip.Amount"), each = length(employees) * 2)), 
  employees)
```

Now, we have all the values we need.  Check that the values are identical to those from your list `t`:

```
all.equal(unname(out), unname(unlist(t)))
# [1] TRUE
```

The remaining steps are to organize the values.  We can put them into a dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(
  type = rep(c("payments", "tips"), each = length(employees) * 2),
  variable = rep(c("amount", "count"), each = length(employees), times = 2),
  employee = rep(employees, times = 4),
  value = out
  )
#        type variable employee      value
# 1  payments   amount        A 0.23278642
# 2  payments   amount        B 0.77047594
# ...
# 7  payments    count        A 0.56123674
# 8  payments    count        B 0.81040604
# ...
# 13     tips   amount        A 0.92749503
# 14     tips   amount        B 0.08716570
# ...
# 23     tips    count        E 0.20672583
# 24     tips    count        F 0.23505606
```

One more step if you want your results as a nested list:

```
y <- lapply(split(d, d$type),
  function(x) lapply(split(x, x$variable),
    function(y) split(y$value, y$employee)
  )
)
all.equal(t, y)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

*Update.*  To get additional values from the `t.test` output, first modify our custom `ttest` function

```
ttest <- function(data, varname, employee) {
  d <- get(data)
  unlist(
    do.call(t.test, setNames(split(d[[varname]], d[[employee]]), c("x", "y")))[c("estimate", "p.value")]
  )
}
```

where in this case we extract values for `estimate` and `p.value` (for the names of other values, you can inspect any `t.test` output, e.g. `str(t.test(1:3, 4:6))`.  The `unlist` function flattens the values we retrieve (originally in the form of a list) into a vector.

Run `mapply` as described above; now, the `out` object is a matrix rather than a vector.  Suppose we want to insert the values into a dataframe:

```
d <- data.frame(
  type = rep(c("payments", "tips"), each = length(employees) * 2),
  variable = rep(c("amount", "count"), each = length(employees), times = 2),
  employee = rep(employees, times = 4),
  x.mean = out[1, ],
  y.mean = out[2, ],
  p.value = out[3, ]
  )
      type variable employee    x.mean    y.mean   p.value
# 1 payments   amount        A 10.217391 10.240741 0.9714363
# 2 payments   amount        B  9.960784 10.510204 0.4022349
# 3 payments   amount        C 10.490196  9.959184 0.4153361
# . ...        ...
```

Comment: Definitely see that it works. Trying to make sense of what you did before marking as correct. You are doing some things that are new to me!

Comment: How would you recommend pulling additional values from the t-test out? I am looking for the x and y mean so I can summarize which direction the difference exists...

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense when I read it, but couldn't figure it out when I tried